# Add a checkbox to allow the labels to be updated whenever the input text changes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I am very new to programming language and am in my first Programming class at my university. For a project we are creating a VERY simple project where the user enters words and the program puts them together. It's day one stuff I know but I'm trying to go for the extra credit and "Add a check box to allow the labels to be updated whenever the input text changes".

I have a program that when you type in two separate words in separate text boxes it displays each word individually and then also the two words combined at the bottom. Our professor wants my to add an check box option at the bottom that when clicked with make it so when the users types the two words they display automatically without clicking the display button.

I know this is easy stuff, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

```
Public Class form1
    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblLeft.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub lbl2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblRight.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtBoxLeft_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBoxLeft.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Dim strTxtBoxLeft As String
        strTxtBoxLeft = txtBoxLeft.Text
        Dim strTxtBoxRight As String
        strTxtBoxRight = txtBoxRight.Text

        lblLeft.Text = strTxtBoxLeft

        lblRight.Text = strTxtBoxRight

        lblCombo.Text = strTxtBoxLeft & " " & strTxtBoxRight
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkbox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkbox.CheckedChanged
        If chkbox.CheckState = False Then

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        combineText()
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkbox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkbox.CheckedChanged
        If chkbox.CheckState = False Then
            lblCombo.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txtBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBoxRight.TextChanged, txtBoxLeft.TextChanged
        If chkbox.CheckState Then
            combineText()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub combineText()
        lblCombo.Text = txtBoxLeft.Text & " " & txtBoxRight.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note: I have consolidated your logic down to just grab the text from the text boxes themselves. There is also one handler that handles text changing in either of the text boxes. Finally, there is a single method that handles combining the values of the two text boxes together, either via the text changed event if the check box is checked or if the user clicks the update button. Also, if the user unchecks the check box, then it will clear the results. Then when the user clicks update it will display the combined text again.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Karl Anderson this worked. This also gives me an idea of what I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: @user2788749 - no problem, good luck with your programming class, feel free to up-vote this answer when you can. :-)

Comment: Will do. Don't have enough "rep" for now.